# Password Generator: Why is there no password being generated in the div with id="generated-password"?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, password-generator

toIncludeCharacters() seems to be working since it returns lower-case letters on upload
generatePassword() seems to be returning a blank output

When you click "Generate Password" button it returns three blank outputs

Can I know why this is so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      <div>
      <label for="length">Length of password:</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="password-length"
        name="password-length"
        min="8"
        max="20"
        placeholder="8"
      />
    </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          id="uppercase-condition"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="upper-case-condition">
          Include uppercase letters
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          id="lowercase-condition"
          checked
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="lowercase-condition">
          Include lowercase letters
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          id="symbols-condition"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="symbols-condition">
          Include symbols
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value=""
          id="numbers-condition"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="numbers-condition">
          Include numbers
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create-password">Generate Password</button>
      <div id="generated-password">1234</div>
    </form>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

```
const passwordLengthCondition = document.getElementById("password-length");
const uppercaseCondition = document.getElementById("uppercase-condition");
const lowercaseCondition = document.getElementById("lowercase-condition");
const symbolsCondition = document.getElementById("symbols-condition");
const numbersCondition = document.getElementById("numbers-condition");

const conditionsChecklist = [
  uppercaseCondition,
  lowercaseCondition,
  symbolsCondition,
  numbersCondition,
];

function toIncludeCharacters() {
  const uppercaseLetters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
  const lowercaseLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\\:;\"'<>,.?/~`";
  const numbers = "1234567890";

  const charactersList = [uppercaseLetters, lowercaseLetters, symbols, numbers];

  let includedCharacters = ""; // Reset the characters for each call

  for (let i = 0; i < conditionsChecklist.length; i++) {
    if (conditionsChecklist[i].checked) {
      includedCharacters += charactersList[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(includedCharacters)
  return includedCharacters;
}

function generatePassword(passwordLength) {
  let password = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    password += toIncludeCharacters().charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * includedCharacters.length));
  }
  console.log(password);
  return password;
}


const generatePasswordButton = document.getElementById("create-password");
generatePasswordButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const passwordLength = parseInt(passwordLengthCondition.value); // Convert to number
  document.getElementById("generated-password").textContent = generatePassword(passwordLength);
  console.log(generatePassword(passwordLength)); // Move this line here
});

const checklist = document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input");
for (let i = 0; i < checklist.length; i++) {
  checklist[i].addEventListener("change", toIncludeCharacters);
}

toIncludeCharacters();
generatePassword();
```

```
#generated-password {
  margin: 3%;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: larger;
}


body {
  margin: 5%;
}

form {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2%;
}

form div, button {
  margin: 1%;
}
```

I want to be able to show a custom password given the condition of password length and characters that should be included.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution explanation

In your `generatePassword` function, it looks like you are getting an error for "includedCharacters" is not defined. This is because you didn't save the returned value of `toIncludeCharacters` function. The value is only fetched once.

The code can be changed to save the returned value to a variable (let's call it `incl_chars`) and then we can use that value for the functions.

### Updated code

So, your updated function becomes:

```
function generatePassword(passwordLength) {
  let password = "";
  incl_chars = toIncludeCharacters()
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    password += incl_chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * incl_chars.length));
  }
  // console.log(password);
  return password;
}
```

And your updated code becomes:

```js
const passwordLengthCondition = document.getElementById("password-length");
const uppercaseCondition = document.getElementById("uppercase-condition");
const lowercaseCondition = document.getElementById("lowercase-condition");
const symbolsCondition = document.getElementById("symbols-condition");
const numbersCondition = document.getElementById("numbers-condition");

const conditionsChecklist = [
  uppercaseCondition,
  lowercaseCondition,
  symbolsCondition,
  numbersCondition,
];

function toIncludeCharacters() {
  const uppercaseLetters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
  const lowercaseLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\\:;\"'<>,.?/~`";
  const numbers = "1234567890";

  const charactersList = [uppercaseLetters, lowercaseLetters, symbols, numbers];

  let includedCharacters = ""; // Reset the characters for each call

  for (let i = 0; i < conditionsChecklist.length; i++) {
    if (conditionsChecklist[i].checked) {
      includedCharacters += charactersList[i];
    }
  }

  // console.log(includedCharacters)
  return includedCharacters;
}

function generatePassword(passwordLength) {
  let password = "";
  incl_chars = toIncludeCharacters()
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    password += incl_chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * incl_chars.length));
  }
  // console.log(password);
  return password;
}


const generatePasswordButton = document.getElementById("create-password");
generatePasswordButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const passwordLength = parseInt(passwordLengthCondition.value); // Convert to number
  document.getElementById("generated-password").textContent = generatePassword(passwordLength);
  // console.log(generatePassword(passwordLength)); // Move this line here
});

const checklist = document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input");
for (let i = 0; i < checklist.length; i++) {
  checklist[i].addEventListener("change", toIncludeCharacters);
}

/*
toIncludeCharacters();
generatePassword();
*/
```

```css
#generated-password {
  margin: 3%;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: larger;
}

body {
  margin: 5%;
}

form {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2%;
}

form div,
button {
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Password Generator</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    <div>
      <label for="length">Length of password:</label>
      <input type="number" id="password-length" name="password-length" min="8" max="20" placeholder="8" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="uppercase-condition" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="upper-case-condition">
          Include uppercase letters
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="lowercase-condition" checked />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="lowercase-condition">
          Include lowercase letters
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="symbols-condition" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="symbols-condition">
          Include symbols
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="numbers-condition" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="numbers-condition">
          Include numbers
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create-password">Generate Password</button>
    <div id="generated-password">1234</div>
  </form>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>`
```

### Suggestion(s)

I would also suggest adding a check to see if the user has entered any value or not in the length box, for your purpose.